# 3D View Render Preview not in sychronization with texture paint, Cycles Render appears correctly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-painting, gpu

Blender 2.83.2
Cycles Render Engine

If I have both an Image Editor and a 3D View in Texture Paint

User Experience for Different 3D View Modes

- 3D View Solid Mode Interactive.. 3D View is updated and Image Editor Updated
- 3D View Material Preview Interactive... 3D View is updated and Image Editor Updated
- 3D View Render Preview  [ Not ] Interactive... 3D View is NOT updated and Image Editor Updated ⚠

Transparency was my emphasis today. Brush Erase Alpha and Add Alpha

Does the dependency mechanism ...topological sort and texture painting .. allow correctly updating in the 3D View ... for the bullet point marked ⚠ ?  I do see work occurring in the 3D View.  I do not know what is the correct expectation.

If I nudge and poke Blender by switching render modes in the 3D Viewport
Shading ..

from Rendered Preview.. to Material Preview .. back to Rendered Preview... then
I can see the correct results in 3D Viewport.  ⍖ File Save Required.⏻

An image on disk and a mask image and Shader Editor are used.   One static on being modified in texture paint. The mask image ..which is just and image with Alpha is used .. it does not have a special designation.  I have saved the modified file which is a mask.  For interactivity I would not want to save it all the time.

This appears in the console .. I am not sure if it is related.
Unsupported mode: OBJECT

As well my GPU is now rejected by Blender. So I would expect slower updating.